# How to find example how to use OpenId Connect in Chrome Extension MV3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, openid-connect, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I try to use libraries like [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) in service worker, but they cannot work in service worker environment, because of missing window and XMLHttpRequest. Please help me to find example of working openid connect in chrome MV3 extension.

Comment: The successor to `oidc-client-js` (`oidc-client-ts`) appears to have be patched to work in a service worker https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts

Answer (score 1):

I removed oidc-client-js and implemented it manually using such sources with launchwebauthflow:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=907920
https://roberttolton.com/posts/implementing-auth0-authentication-into-a-chrome-extension